# Dynamic content display with Naked Objects or Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, jquery, domain-driven-design, dynamic-data, naked-objects

I need to develop a POC (.NET, C#, ASP.NET...). The application should create WebPages dynamically from domain objects. The application is about collecting new potential clients and it is a lot about UX. In such scenarios, we often need some kind of JQuery to show or hide fields according to other fields selections, and we need very flexible client-side validation policies.

I was thinking about creating a DSL with Microsoft DSL Toolkit (with T4), but now, I definitely think it would be much better to render my WebPages at runtime. I am very interested in Naked Objects. On Microsoft side, there is Dynamic Data.

Do you think these frameworks are suitable for my POC, or should I abandon because I am looking for something that does not exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declared bias:  I am the products manager of the open source Naked Objects framework. (Also, both your posting and my response might get criticised for being an unsuitable topic  -  request for product advice  - for Stack Overflow.  But meantime ...)

Yes, I absolutely think Naked Objects would be suitable for what you want -  try it out. If what you ultimately need is more UI control than Naked Objects offers then you can switch to using the Restful Objects API (see http://restfulobjects.org/ ) which is also auto-generated from the identical domain model by the Naked Objects framework - and consuming that via a JavaScript front end.  In which case you should also take a look at Spiro (https://github.com/SpiroLibraries )

FYI Microsoft's Dynamic Data was a nice idea, but it has been a dead project for quite a long time now -  I was in touch with the original architect of it, David Ebbo for whom I have a lot of respect, just last week.